# Can i use the overpass Api to make calls for a location based unity game?

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

I currently develop a location based game similar like pokemon go with unity.

Each user find themselfe on top of a map which based on the real gps data(latitude longitude) and get updated on moving. I dont need a lot of details for the flat map, streets and every kind of walkable path and probably obstacles like houses or rivers which could block the paths.

Can i use the overpass api to realize something like explained above ? Can you show me a example of how i could start.